# Specify 'songs' tab for MPMediaPickerController

Tags: tabs, ios7, mpmediapickercontroller

Good day- I have some code that opens the MPMediaPickerController:

```
MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];

mediaPicker.delegate = self;
mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = NO;

// show media picker
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];

[mediaPicker release];
```

Since iOS7, the picker defaults to the 'playlists' tab. Is there a way to make it default to the 'songs' tab (or any other tab) ? Thanks.

Comment: have you find any solution to specify songs tab..

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the default tab of the `MPMediaPickerController`, as you have already mentioned prior to iOS 7 the defaults tab of the MPMediaPickerController was songs tab , but in ios 7 they have changed it to playlist tab!

For more info you can check the [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMediaPickerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) which doesn't mention anything like this.

Sorry, It's not a regular `UITabBarController`.